# Getting the @param comments for a method in Java

Tags: java, parsing

Is there a way to get the @param comments for a method in Java?  I know it could be easily achieved by parsing each java file.  However this seems like something that should already be available in a tool like JavaCC.

Example - I want to be able to read ch and observer:

```
* @param ch        the character to be tested
* @param observer  the image observer to be notified
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the sources, you might like to consider using [QDox](http://qdox.codehaus.org/) which is described as a high speed, small footprint parser for extracting class/interface/method definitions from source files complete with JavaDoc @tags. It is designed to be used by active code generators or documentation tools.

Sample code [from documentation](http://qdox.codehaus.org/model.html):

```
JavaMethod mth = cls.getMethods()[0];

// Access the JavaDoc comment
String comment = mth.getComment();
  // "This method does nothing at all."

// Access a single doclet tag
DocletTag returns = mth.getTagByName("returns");
returns.getName(); // "returns";
returns.getValue(); // "A boolean of whether we care or not."

// Access multiple doclet tags with the same name
DocletTag[] params = mth.getTagsByName("param");
params[0].getValue(); // "Someone's email address."
params[1].getValue(); // "Date of birth."

// Access specific parameters of a doclet tag by index
DocletTag permission = mth.getTagByName("permission");
permission.getParameter[0]; // "administrator"
permission.getParameter[1]; // "full-access"

// Access specific parameters of a doclet tag by name
DocletTag webservice = mth.getTagByName("webservice");
webservice.getNamedParameter("type"); // "rpc"
webservice.getNamedParameter("name"); // "myservice"
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to the  @param in the javadoc comments? Javac (or do you really mean JavaCC the java compiler compiler?) ignores them as those are just comments.
You could use the javadoc tool though, can write your own doclet even nowadays if memory serves.

Or are you referring to a method annotation? Those can be retrieved in java code if retention is set to runtime on the annotation declaration.

Comment: OK so javadoc stuff, but my answer covers that I'm afraid, you can't get that from standard java class files. If they are compiled with debug information you could get them from the class file using class (bytecode) inspection tools/libraries. So indeed you would need to parse the java source files, but a javadoc doclet could do it for you or some fancy regexps I guess. Javac ignores comments, and javadoc is basically fancy comments.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can run a doclet from within another class in Java - damn!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "no": Comments are not accessible at runtime, because comments are *not* compiled into the `.class` file.

You could parse the source (if available) using various method, but that seems off topic for your question.